# How to print a specific row without using pattern matching

Tags: awk, sed

Is there a way to print a specific row (without using pattern matching) like we use to print column ($1, $2, $3 etc)?

My Text file:

```
Hi
How are you?
I am from California.
```

Is there any special characters to achieve this like $1, $2, $3 etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
~$ sed -n '3p' myfile
I am from California.
```

Using awk

```
~$ awk 'NR==3' myfile
I am from California.
```

---

If the file is large, you should exit when the line is found:

Using sed:

```
~$ sed -n '3{p;q}' myfile
I am from California.
```

Using awk

```
~$ awk 'NR==3{print;exit}' myfile
I am from California.
```

Comment: In perl, it would be like `perl -lane 'print if $.==3' file`

Comment: If file is large, this is better: `awk 'NR==3 {print;exit}' myfile`, since it stops when line is found.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use either sed or awk to do this but if you wanted to use python, you could do this:

```
with open('file') as f: 
    for i, l in enumerate(f): 
        if i == 2: 
            print l.rstrip()
            break
```

Though slightly longer, there are a couple of advantages to this approach. Firstly, the whole file isn't read into memory to begin with (as would be the case with `readlines()`). Secondly, the loop is terminated once the desired line is read, rather than continuing to the end of the file.

I have used `.rstrip()` to remove trailing space characters from the line, including newlines. Thanks to [Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) for pointing that out.

My preferred choice would be to use awk in the following way:

```
awk 'NR==2{print;exit}' file
```

This executes the block when the record (line) number is 2, so prints the second line then exits.

Comment: your python code must print a new line character. So change your print statement like `print(l.replace('\n',''))`

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open("file.txt",'r')
print f.readlines()[<any number you want>]
```

Comment: I want to specify to print only 1st row or 2nd row... Its not possible using this code right?